# trouble with the timelineVariable() in jsPsych - shows up as 'undefined'

Tags: javascript, jspsych

I am a beginner in JsPsych and new to JS as well. I am having some difficulty with using the `JsPsych.timelineVariable()`. Just to get myself oriented with the program, I am trying to code a simple math quiz. I made an object of math questions, and used the documentation on jsPsych to reference the object as the prompt for my survey text variable. But, when I open the html file, I see 'undefined' in place of the prompt. If I replace the prompt command with a string, it works fine, so I know I am doing something wrong with the `timelineVariable()`. I tried it in two different ways, with the first way commented out:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head> <!-- all preloads go into head -->
    <title>Math Quiz</title>
    <!-- any plugins go here-->
    <script src="jspsych/dist/jspsych.js"></script>
    <script src = "jspsych/dist/plugin-survey-text.js"></script>
    <link href="jspsych/dist/jspsych.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body> <!-- all script for tasks go into body-->
    <script> 
    
    var jsPsych = initJsPsych();
/*
    var timeline = [];

  
    var mathQuestions = [
        {math: '2+2 = ?', correct: '4'},
        {math: '2x3 = ?', correct: '6'},
        {math: '5x7 = ?', correct: '35'}
    ];

    var test = {
        type: jsPsychSurveyText,
        questions: [
            {prompt: jsPsych.timelineVariable('math'), 
            name: 'resp'}
        ]
    };
*/

var test = {
    timeline: [ 
        {
            type: jsPsychSurveyText,
            stimulus: jsPsych.timelineVariable('math')
        }
    ],

    timeline_variables: [
        { math: '2+2'},
        { math: '3+5'},
        { math: '10+7'}
    ]
}

    jsPsych.run([test]);

    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

You've got bits of the right idea in both of the examples, but they need to be combined together. The first code chunk doesn't work because the `test` trial is not on a timeline with timeline variables attached. The second chunk doesn't work because the SurveyText plugin doesn't have a `stimulus` parameter.

I think this should work:

```js
var timeline = [];

var mathQuestions = [
  {math: '2+2 = ?', correct: '4'},
  {math: '2x3 = ?', correct: '6'},
  {math: '5x7 = ?', correct: '35'}
];

var test = {
  type: jsPsychSurveyText,
  questions: [
    {
      prompt: jsPsych.timelineVariable('math'), 
      name: 'resp'
    }
  ]
};

var mathQuestionProcedure = {
  timeline: [test],
  timeline_variables: mathQuestions
}
timeline.push(mathQuestionProcedure)
```